# SimpleCursorAdapter, Swapping cursor in API level below 11

Tags: android, android-cursor

Trying to implement LoaderManager + CursorLoader.

In onFinish method adapter should swap its cursor

```
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
  }
```

But swapCursor is available since API Level 11.

So how should I swap cursor in android API 10 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) has needed implementations.

It's http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Android Studio suggestion to wrap and [swapCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor))'s explanation that the old cursor wasn't close, using android.widget.CursorAdapter, you get:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    } else {
        Cursor oldCursor = mAdapter.getCursor();
        mAdapter.changeCursor(data);
        oldCursor.close();
    }
}
```